# Zimbra prevents server website from loading?

Tags: centos, centos6, zimbra

I have a server with Linux CentOS 6 installed. 
I have a website on that server, normal port 80, which was running perfectly.

I installed Zimbra ZCS 8, it is running on port 8080, but now my website does not load anymore.

I thought the problem might be the httpd service, but this is running perfectly.

What could be the problem??

Answer (score 1):

You probably install ZCS with proxy, jetty turn on 8080, the proxy zimbra running on 80/443 ( default port ) you have to change these ports by executing this command :

> su - zimbra
>
> ./libexec/zmproxyconfig -e -w -o -a 8080:**9080**:8443:**9443** -x
>     -H `zmhostname`